# Include Adorner in ScrollViewer scrollable region

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, adorner

I currently have an `Adorner` inside a `ScrollViewer`. Objects at the bottom of the scrollviewer can sometimes display a large adorner below them. Unfortunately, that adorner is not included in the `ExtentHeight` of the scrollviewer, so the lower portion of the adorner is clipped by the bottom of the scrollviewer's viewport.

Is there a way to get the adorner layer's contents to be included in the scrollable region of the scrollviewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the consensus from other sources and hours of investigation seems to be that what I mentioned simply isn't possible. My solution has been simply to detect the last item in my ListBox and automatically add a margin to its bottom when my Adorner is being displayed. It's a bit of a hack, but it achieves the desired behavior mentioned above.